# OpenJDK 11 - java.security.NoSuchProviderException:no such provider: nCipherKM

Tags: java, cryptography, java-11, hsm, openjdk-11

I am trying to configure nCipherKM Security provider with OpenJDK11.
With jdk8 I had to add the provider to the java.security file and add the provider jar file to jre/lib/ext and it was working fine.
Since external libraries are not allowed in the later jdk versions how can I add a provider on OpenJDK 11?

I have performed the following to configure the security provider with openjdk 11 -

1. Added the nCipherKM.jar to the CLASSPATH by creating a CLASSPATH  environment variable
2. Added the security provider to the java.security file under openjdk11/conf/security/

   `security.provider.14=nCipherKM`
   I've also tried
   `security.provider.14=com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM`
3. java.Security.Provider file found in the nCipherKM.jar under nCipherKM\META-INF\services\
   contains
   `com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM`
4. To validate if the provider was registered, I ran the command -

   ```
   java --module-path %NFAST_HOME%\java\classes com.ncipher.provider.InstallationTest
   ```

   I get the below output which indicates that the provider has been installed fine.

   > unlimited strength jurisdiction files are installed.
   > The nCipher provider is installed, but is not registered at
   > the top of the providers list in the java.security file. See
   > the user guide for more information about the recommended

However, when I run my application, I still see the error -

```
 [java.security.NoSuchProviderException:no such provider: nCipherKM]-> 
 [java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:83)
```

I'd like to know what am I missing here. Thank you for the help!

Comment: So you are following the installation documentation https://nshielddocs.entrust.com/api-generic/12.80/jca-jce-csp?

Comment: Try adding security.provider.1=nCipherKM instead of security.provider.14=nCipherKM

Comment: @Robert Yes, I'm following the documentation from nshielddocs.entrust.com . @Thiago Henrique Hupner
I did change the  nCipherKm provider to be the the first security.provider on the list.  This time the installationTest failed unless I added the fully qualified class name for the provider . I also had to pass the Classpath with the Java command and now the NoSuchProviderException is gone. However, I get a new error now -  ```:The private key material is not exportable outside of the HSM][javax.net.ssl.SSLException:The private key material is not exportable outside of the HSM```

Answer (score -1):

as a first check you need to ensure that if more than one version of Java is installed in your system, if your application is working with the correct version.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the inputs. I do have jd8 and openjdk11 on this system, but my application is using openjdk11 it doesn't use JAVA_HOME that's set to JDK8.  Would that still be an issue?